# Trying to use Excel VBA to combine data together from multiple spreadsheets, but my loop keeps saving over previously saved data

Tags: vba, excel

I found a website that has a macro that lets you complete a looped action for all spreadsheets in a file folder.  I've used this macro as the basis for my macro below: [See Link Here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder)

I've been able to use it successfully for a few other projects, but I'm running into some issues on my current project.  I have a number of spreadsheets in a file folder that I'm attempting to open, copy the data, then paste into a master spreadsheet.  The goal is to put all the data from the many spreadsheets, into one singular spreadsheet.  The list of the many spreadsheets in the file folder is a dynamic list that will change over time.  So I can't simply individually reference every spreadsheet, that's why I'm trying to use the looping strategy from the link above.

The problem I'm having is some of the pastes are getting pasted over previous spreadsheet's values.  So instead of each spreadsheet getting pasted at the bottom of the previous's values, some are getting pasted in the middle and overwriting information that I need.  I think my problem is that excel is getting confused as to which spreadsheet should be referenced when I gets into the row.count, copy/paste section of the code and the variables for i & j are getting assigned incorrectly.  But I can't figure out how to fix this.  I'm out of ideas, and thoroughly frustrated!  Apologies if I'm screwing up something rather basic, but I'm rather new to VBA.

```
Sub CombineReports()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  myPath = "I:\Pricing\mt access\Tier Reports\Final Reports\"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    'Worksheet tasks

    i = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A5", "N" & i).Copy
    Workbooks.Open ("I:\Pricing\mt access\Tier Reports\Final Reports\Combined Report\CombinedTierReport.xlsx")
    j = Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Worksheets("AllStores").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Worksheets("AllStores").Range("A" & j + 1, "N" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Save
    Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Close

    DoEvents

    'Save and Close Workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
        Loop

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Range("A" & j + 1, "N" & i)` to `Range("A" & j + 1)`. a) the syntax is wrong b) you only need the top-left cell of a paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Range("A" & j + 1, "N" & i)` to `Range("A" & j + 1)`. a) the range is wrong and b) you only need the top-left cell of a paste.

```
...
i = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wb.Worksheets(1).range("A5", "N" & i).Copy
with Workbooks.Open ("I:\Pricing\mt access\Tier Reports\Final Reports\Combined Report\CombinedTierReport.xlsx")
    j = .Worksheets("AllStores").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Worksheets("AllStores").Range("A" & j + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Save
    .Close savechanges:=false
end with
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!  Sanity has been restored, I'm glad it was a simple fix.